# Cannot find module 'next-intl/client'

Tags: typescript, testing, next.js

After npm run test I have this error:

*Cannot find module 'next-intl/client'*

```
jest.mock(
         |      ^
      22 |   'next-intl/client',
      23 |   (): Record<string, unknown> => ({
      24 |     usePathname: (): string => '/en',
```

Tried to uninstall npm, node, next-intl folder. Installed different versions but nothing works.
I don't have a "client" folder in "next-intl".
Somebody knows what's the problem?

Comment: An older or newer version?

Comment: Next - 13.5.6, "next-intl": "^3.0.0-beta.16", node - 20.10.0

Comment: Try v2. The one likely has breaking changes

Answer (score 0):

In my project requirements was node 18.16.0. But I cloned that project in 18.6.0 version and then updated it to 20.10.0.
I tried to reinstall node_modules and package.lock.json but that didn't help.

> Just full reinstall of project to node 18.16.0 from git repository
> helped